# Is there any way to activate the Apply button from a print propery page with PrintDlgEx?

Tags: winapi, printing, dialog

I have custom print property sheets/pages that have been added to the dialog displayed by PrintDlgEx. These property sheets are, of course, used to change additional options. The issue is that there does not appear to be any documented way to activate the Apply button from the property sheet's dialog function, or anywhere for that matter. This seems to be a huge omission on Microsoft's part.

Is there any "official" way to change the Apply button's state? If not, are there any possible workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any "official" way to change the Apply button's state? If not, are there any possible workarounds?

Not directly, no.  You would have to retrieve the button's HWND manually an then manipulate it as needed.

1. use [`SetWindowHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to install a local `WH_CBT` hook for the thread that is calling `PrintDlgEx()`. The dialog's HWND will be available as a parameter of the callback function when it receives a `HCBT_ACTIVATE` notification.  Then you can locate the `Apply` button's HWND within the dialog (use Spy++ or similar tool to get details about the button, then have your code use [`GetDlgItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`FindWindowEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the button's HWND).  Be sure to call [`UnhookWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after `PrintDlgEx()` exits (or at least after you are done using the button HWND).
2. use [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register for `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE`, `EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW`, and/or `EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART` notification(s) for the thread that is calling `PrintDlgEx()`. The dialog and button HWNDs will be available as a parameter of the callback function.  Be sure to call [`UnhookWinEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after `PrintDlgEx()` exits (or at least after you are done using the button HWND).

Once you have the button's HWND, you can do whatever you want with it.  It is a standard button control, so any standard button message/function can be used with it.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about something similar too, but my idea wasn't as good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A more close to "official" way is to call PropSheet_Changed().
The way I get the property sheet dialog is to look at the source of PSN_ notifications sent to IPrintDialogCallback::HandleMessage(). Or you can use GetParent(GetParent(generalDialog)).

Once you call PropSheet_Changed() the Apply button will activate.

You're right, it seems to be a huge omission on Microsoft's part, as it's not a simple thing to code, but it's something that most people adding property sheets would need.

I can put some code up if anyone needs it.

Comment: This is very good! I finished the project last year, but I didn't notice the macros in property sheet reference pages on MSDN back then.